# Copy filtered sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet which is filtered; I want to copy only the filtered data into a variable called `varTable` - see code below.

If the data is not filtered that all the data is copied in ok;

If I apply a filter (manually - not via VBA) then I would expect only the visible lines to be copied ; but this is not the case ; the result are variable depending on which filter I apply;

can anyone help please?

```
Dim varTable As Variant

varTable = DataSh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' identifies no of rows
MsgBox UBound(varTable, 1)

'identifies no of columns

MsgBox UBound(varTable, 2)
```

Comment: You will need to iterate through the areas of the visible range and add each line to the array individually.  there is no way to add a disjointed range in mass to a variant array variable

Comment: Hi Scott, not quite sure how to iterate through - can you give me a tip please. thanks!

Comment: Hi Scott - don't worry - I've remembered how to do this!